# Find an object that other canvas object is overlapping with - Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want to detect with what canvas object `block`. We have `block, circle and triangle` canvas objects.

I know there is `if block in canvas.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2):` method but doesn't shows with what object is `block` overlapping. It just shows if `block` is touching with any other canvas object.

`overlapping_object=canvas.find_overlapping(block)`, `overlapping_object` could be a list that shows tags of objects that is `block` touching with.

How to make `overlapping_object=canvas.find_overlapping(block)` but it's correct. This one I typed here is just how could it look.

Thanks for any help!

I'm making 2D minecraft in tkinter and this is the thing that can really speed up my process.

Comment: I would consider looking outside of tkinter. Consider this answer posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636047/python-shapely-find-if-parts-of-two-multi-polygons-overlap

Comment: sorry, ran across this as well.
can also see this one which is specifically about circles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422734/how-to-check-if-a-circle-is-overlapping-or-inside-a-second-circle-and-if-a-point  though you could do it with the geometry library

Comment: @Ash this helps me neither. I'm doing it with tkinter and nothing else.

Comment: I will add that there are multiple game engines built in python. Tkinter is about the worst gui program (imo) to use for that task. It's not optimized for games.  Pygame 2.0 or one of the others would work far easier than tkinter. Tkinter is... more for applications like if you're building a text editor or the like. I even made a boilerplate manager in windows from tkinter. But I would suggest reevaluating why you're wanting to use tkinter to work in. I mean you can dig a trench with a dinner spoon but a shovel works a lot better, you know what I mean?

Comment: @Ash yes I know what you mean, and thanks. I started to notice that tkinter is hard to create games - these .place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5) are really hard to. Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. You can get the coordinates of `block` and then call `find_overlapping` with those coordinates, and it will return a list of all objects that are overlapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not willing to use other libraries and only tkinter, I don't think there's a built in function in tkinter that will allow it.  I am also not sure why everything must be done in tkinter as it's not at all unusual for programs to use multiple libraries. Personally, given tikinter's limitations, I would use pygame to track polygons and their intersection but would never draw them. Short of using a third library (tikinter, python default, and other), there is one other approach. I mean it's really the only appraoch.

good ole fashioned math.
https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/93intersection/
Here's some documentation on how to go about doing that. I wish you luck.

EDIT:
I think I accidentally found the answer to your question using math while studying for some other stuff.  Still no way IN tkinter but here's a math explanation.

```
circle with center (x,y) and radius r
Polygon with z number of sides with x*2-1 number of points(x,y)
```

If you take iterate the lines of the polygon and put them through the following maths

```
Line J (x1,y1)(x2,y2)
m of Line J = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)

create line P from circle center to P1 of LineJ
create line O from circle center to P2 of LineJ
```

Now we have a triangle

```
take the inverse cosine and length of P and O to get angle of the triangle you just made.

Make a right triangle by bisecting the triangle with line K starting at circle center and going out at the angle you just calculated.
```

Now you have line P and 1/2 angle of line P to line K

Now to find the intercept of that mid angle line

```
Tan(1/2 angle) = slope or m of the new line
using the x,y of the circle center calculate the slope intercept formula y=mx+b and get b
```

Now take the slope intercept formula for line J and set it equal to the slope intercept of the new line

```
line J (mx + b) = y = line P (mx + b)
Solve for y
```

Then plug y in the slope intercept for either and solve for x.

Once you've done this you have 4 points. The three points of the triangle, the point that makes a perpendicular line to center of circle from line J.

If any 3 of those points  to the center of the circle in distance is smaller than r, they overlap. If they are are all > r then they don't overlap.

Comment: _" I don't think there's a built in function in tkinter that will allow it."_ - there is.